# Help with a sequence proof problem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I have the following theorem to prove, and the book makes a certain suggestion that I don't understand.

### Theorem

Suppose that the sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ converges to $l$ and that the sequence $\{b_{n}\}$ has the property that there exists an index $K$ such that $a_{n}=b_{n}$ for all $n \geq K$.

Show that $\{b_{n}\}$ also converges to $l$.

### Questions

So the book makes a suggestion that I use the comparison lemma for a quick proof. The comparison lemma is the following.

Let the sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ converge to the number $a$. Then the sequence $\{b_{n}\}$ converges to the number $b$ if there is a non-negative number $C$ and an index $N$ such that

$\lvert b_{n} - b \rvert \leq C \lvert a_{n}-a\rvert$

But what I was thinking was that all I have to do is pick some $n$ larger than or equal to $K$ and then, since I am guaranteed now that $a_{n}=b_n$, that I can just substitue

if from our assumption $\lvert a_n - l \rvert$ $<$ $\epsilon$ for all $n$ larger than some $N$.

All I have to do is first pick $n$ to be larger than $K$, and then pick $n$ larger still so that it is larger than or equal to N, and then I will have that $\lvert b_n -l \rvert < \epsilon$

Therefore $b_n$ would converge like we want it to. Even if the $N$ necessary to make the sequence $a_n$ converge  to $l$ is less than $K$ it wouldn't hurt things at all.

I was wondering if anybody could see any flaws in my thinking. I wrote a bit more than I would for a real solution, but I was just wondering how the comparison lemma would save any time rather than just making things more complicated.

I mean in plain english this thing just says if my a sequence converges and after some point all my b's are a's then the b sequence will converge to the same point. I feel like I'm over thinking it.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(a_n)$ is converge to $l,$ for each $\epsilon >0$ there exist an integer $N(\epsilon)$ such that $|a_n-l|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N(\epsilon).$
Let $N(\epsilon,   K)=\max(K,N(\epsilon))$
Then $|b_n-l|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N(\epsilon,   K).$
Hence $(b_n)$ is also converge to $l.$

Comment: You can use your lemma also with $b=a, C=2$ and $N=K.$

Answer (score 0):

A sequence has the limit $l$ means: for every $\epsilon >0$ **all but finitely many terms** of the sequence are at distance $<\epsilon$ from $l$.

It follows that the convergence of a sequence to a limit depends only on the $\it{multiset}$
$\{a_n \}$ and this one can also be modified with finitely many elements ( add or substract).

For instance a sequence with multiset $\{ \infty \cdot 1, \infty \cdot 2, 3\}$ is not convergent since it has two subsequences with limit $1$, respectively $2$.

Another quick consequence is that permuting a sequence does not affect the convergence.